# Why is Debian 12 crashing to login screen?

Tags: debian, memory, hardware, crash, mate-desktop

Situation: In the last month or two, occasionally while browsing with either Brave or Firefox I click a hyperlink and the machine crashes back to the login screen. After logging again, anything previously opened is closed and any work in progress lost. Sometimes a link clicked on in Brave causes a crash, but maybe not in Firefox, and vice versa. I upgraded from Debian 11 to 12, but it continues.

It's now crashed on several different sites. For awhile it looked like the same links were doing it, but the links do not always cause a crash. Sometimes crashes when I resize a browser window. Once after it went into hibernate mode and I woke it up to logon. Crashed as soon as I entered my credentials.

System:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 6.1.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.69-1 (2023-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ inxi -Fxz

System:
  Kernel: 6.1.0-17-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 12.2.0
    Desktop: MATE v: 1.26.0 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 6475HA0 v: ThinkPad T400
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 6475HA0 v: ThinkPad T400 serial: <superuser required>
    BIOS: coreboot v: CBET4000 4.15-201-g6a8bf6d6a5 date: 12/20/2021
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 57.9 Wh (95.9%) condition: 60.4/84.2 Wh (71.7%)
    volts: 12.4 min: 10.8 model: SANYO 42T4530 status: not charging
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse
    charge: 55% (should be ignored) status: discharging
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core2 Quad Q9000 bits: 64 type: MCP
    arch: Penryn rev: A cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 6 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1600 min/max: 1600/2001 boost: enabled cores: 1: 1600
    2: 1600 3: 1600 4: 1600 bogomips: 16001
  Flags: ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Mobile 4 Series Integrated Graphics vendor: Lenovo
    driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-5 bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: Lenovo Integrated Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 7-6:2
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: crocus gpu: i915 resolution: 1: 1440x900~60Hz
    2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 2.1 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: Mesa Mobile Intel GM45 Express
    (CTG) direct-render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 82801I HD Audio vendor: Lenovo ThinkPad T400
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
  API: ALSA v: k6.1.0-17-amd64 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 status: active
  Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: off (using pipewire-pulse)
Network:
  Device-1: Intel 82567LM Gigabit Network vendor: Lenovo ThinkPad T400
    driver: e1000e v: kernel port: 1000 bus-ID: 00:19.0
  IF: eno0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Apple AirPort Extreme driver: ath9k v: kernel bus-ID: 02:00.0
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 223.57 GiB used: 135.15 GiB (60.5%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37240G size: 223.57 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 217.55 GiB used: 135.02 GiB (62.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1
    mapped: debian--vg-root
  ID-2: /boot size: 469.4 MiB used: 129.3 MiB (27.5%) fs: ext2
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 976 MiB used: 6 MiB (0.6%) dev: /dev/dm-2
    mapped: debian--vg-swap_1
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): fan-1: 2675 fan-2: 2675
Info:
  Processes: 244 Uptime: 3d 18h 32m Memory: 7.41 GiB used: 2.02 GiB (27.3%)
  Init: systemd target: graphical (5) Compilers: gcc: 12.2.0 Packages: 3800
  Shell: Bash v: 5.2.15 inxi: 3.3.26
```

I thought it might be a window manager issue, but the X logs before and after were identical.  Any guidance on troubleshooting this issue is greatly appreciated.

---

Edit:
Today, 1/22/2024, for the first time it crashed down to login from screen lock. I had been away for a few minutes and it's set to lock the screen and turn off the monitor. I woke it up, signed back in, and it crashed right away.

---

Edit:
1/25/2024, it crashed when resizing a window in Brave.

---

Edit:
1/28/2024: Over the last 48 hours went through 14 passes with memtest86+ and all PASS with no errors. Then logged into SE, poked around for a bit, and a random link in SE crashed it.  I am now using LXDE for window manager for awhile to see if the crashing was isolated to Mate. Also removed Linphone, as during one controlled reboot the calls daemon was having trouble halting.

It's a very old refurbished laptop, a Lenovo ThinkPad T400. Could something inside be starting to fail?

How could I determine if this is a software or hardware issue? I've used Linux a long time and haven't had anything like this happen. I've had this machine for about 2 years. Bought it from someone who refurbishes them in England. It's been rock-solid until about 2 months ago.

Any insight on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Time to run https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/memtest86+ . Stop the GUI, install from console to maximize the chances.

Comment: @A.B Thanks a lot. I'll check it out and see how to run it.

Comment: @A.B 14 passes and no errors found. And during that time, the CPU never got hotter than 86. But it's nice to be able to rule out the memory. I switched from Mate to LXDE to see if it still crashes.